# How To Remove Characters?

Tags: c++, hex

I'm start(really starting) an Assembly tool, at the time it only converts a decimal to a hexadecimal, but I want to remove the zeros from the result. Here is the code:

```
// HexConvert.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int decNumber;
    while (true)
    {
       cout << "Enter the decimal number: ";
       cin >> decNumber;
       // Print hexadecimal with leading zeros
       cout << "Hexadecimal: ";
       for (int i = 2*sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
          cout << "0123456789ABCDEF"[((decNumber >> i*4) & 0xF)];
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this function directly from C++, but you may have to save some registers, dependig on the compiler. Have fun retranslating to C++.

```
        ;number to convert in [esp+4]
        ;pointer to string in [esp+8]

itoh:   mov edi, [esp+8]   ;pointer to c string
        bsr ecx, eax       ;calculate highest set bit
        and cl, $fc        ;round down to nearest multiple of 4
loop:   mov eax, [esp+4]
        shr eax, cl        ;mov hex digit to lowest 4 bit
        and eax, $f        ;mask hex digit
        cmp eax, 10        ;test if digit is in A..F
        jlt numdgt
        add eax, 'A'-'0'-10 ;it is
numdgt: add eax, '0'       ;ascii converted digit
        mov [edi], al      ;store to string
        inc edi            ;and increment pointer
        sub cl,4           ;decrement loop counter
        jnc loop
        mov byte[edi], 0   ;terminate string
        ret
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the Assembly code, I'm going to use it, this is very simple for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop should have two states:

1. Starting state which ignores '0'
   characters, but switches to the next
   state on non-'0'
2. Print every character to the end.

So, the first state will need to check each character before printing.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your tip, but I'm going to improve it, this was just  a test.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
int number = 56;
cout << hex << number;
```

You could also pass through stringstream to get the hex string representation, with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main () {
    int number = 45;
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << std::hex << number;
    std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
}
```

And more info on stringstreams and fromString/toString: http://cplusplus.co.il/2009/08/16/implementing-tostring-and-fromstring-using-stdstringstream/

Comment: It's good, but I want to learn, then I want to build all this functions by myself **;)**

Comment: In that case, I'd keep a flag to indicate whether or not I have encountered a first non zero. While its not set and there zeroes - dont print them. When you encounter a non-zero, set flag to true and start printing all. Important thing to note here is that if the number is zero you won't print anything, so you need to take care of that as well.

But generally speaking, I think re-inventing the wheel is not a good idea in most cases.. Unless you want this as an exercise ofcourse.